# Relabeling chart series collections

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have written code to plot a graph which is supposed to show one name for each collection.

There are 10 ~ 15 collections so having names for every item in the chart gets messy.

My Excel looks like this in intake port parameter sheet and the graph is plotted between v1 and v2. a is the variable name and case is the case of the variable.

I want all the points to group near one place and have one "a" or "b" as a caption for entire group depending on the group

```
name case V1 V2
a      1  10 11
a      2  12 11
a      3  12 12
a      4  12 11
a      5  12 12

b      1  15 12
b      2  10 10
b      3  15 11
b      4  12 15
b      5  19 12

C      1  01 02
C      2  02 01
C      3  02 11
....
```

```vb
For j = 2 To i
a = 4 + (j - 1) * 6
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Name = "=INTAKE_PORT_PARAMETER!C" & a
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).XValues = "=INTAKE_PORT_PARAMETER!Z" & a & ":Z" & a + 5
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Values = "=INTAKE_PORT_PARAMETER!AA" & a & ":AA" & a + 5
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Item(1).Select
Selection.ShowSeriesName = True
Selection.ShowValue = False
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).DataLabels.Select
Selection.ShowValue = False
Next j
```

When run manually (by clicking F8) the code is working.
The output dots in the graph looks as I want.

```
|   ..(a)
|  ..        **(b)
|
|      ## (C)
|____________________
```

When run using F5 instead of step by step, I get one value for each collection and the name of the collection is not visible.

```
|   ..(10)
|  ..        **(15)
|
|      ## (01)
|____________________
```

I couldn't post the pictures of the graphs. My company treats those as confidential data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. It is difficult to replicate your problem without some input data sample and graph screenshot.

Comment: hie there.. i have updated the question.. Please check it now.. hope it is understandable now..

Comment: is the chart _active_ when using F5?

Comment: yes, it is active.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear in several ways.

Are V1 and V2 your X and Y values? If so, it's easy with a few formulas. The formula in cell E2, filled into E2:G14, is

=IF(E$1=$A2,$D2,NA())

[image: Data split into separate XY series]

Select C1:C14, then hold Ctrl while selecting E1:G14, and insert your scatter chart.

[image: Data plotted as separate XY series]